# Remove and add css classes on Jquery click function

Tags: jquery, onclick

I would appreciate in any one can help me on subject.

My HTML code looks like this..

```
        <div class="product-filter clearfix">
        <div id="product-filter" class="display">
        <span style="float: left;">Display:</span>
        <button class="list btn btn-small">List</button>
        <button class="grid active btn btn-small">Grid</span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="filter-items">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        some text
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

What I need is, when "list button" is clicked, it should add "active" class to it and remove "active" class from "Grid button". Further, it should also remove all "col-md-* and col-lg*" classes from #filter-items div and add col-md-5 and col-lg-5 accordingly.
viceversa it should behave when Grid button is clicked

Comment: Is that all? And what have you tried to make this happen ?

Comment: Given the 'question,' I'm a little curious that you don't appear to be asking for our consulting rates as well.

Comment: i will suggest you to learn basics of jquery else you can do some google/research before asking any question.

Comment: @david what's your rate for keeping your curiosity to your very small self ?

Comment: @kandinski: you can’t afford it.

Answer (score 0):

For your HTML you'd need to add an ID to the button:

```
<button id="btnList" class="list btn btn-small">List</button>
```

Then in JavaScript you have the following (which will make all grids active, for a single grid give it an ID and use the hash (#)):

```
$("#btnList").click(function() {
    $(".grid").addClass("active");
});
```

I do agree with the above comments. This is an incredibly basic question, which is actually answered in the jQuery documentation here:

[jQuery API .click() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

[jQuery API CSS documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/)